# Can someone explain me a line of code in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Could someone please explain me what does this line of code actually means step by step.

```
arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
```

I understand the push part but I am struggling to grasp the code in the parenthesis.

The whole function looks like this :

```
function arrayCalc (arr, fn) {

    arrRes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        arrRes.push(fn(arr[i])); // <--- this line here in the parenthesis

    }
    return arrRes;
};
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I've watched the tutorial video for five times and I just can't understand what that line exactly means.

Thanks!

Comment: It gets the `i`th item in `arr` and passes it to the function `fn` which is called. This result is pushed into `arrRes`.

Comment: `fn(arr[i])` calls `fn` with argument `arr[i]` - note, that functions in javascript are first class, meaning, that an argument to `arrayCalc` can be a function (and `fn` should, in this case).

Comment: its same as `let data = fn(arr[i]);` `arrRes.push(data);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually called a mapping: apply a function to each element of a collection... Thus if you have an array [1,2,3] and map it with a function that multiplies a number by 2, you will end with an array equals to [2,4,6].

To compute it, you need an array, `arr` and a function `fn`. Then for each element of `arr` in turn you apply `fn` to it and place the result at the end of the new collection. You can write it as:

```
arrRes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var dummy = arr[i]; 
    var mapped = fn(dummy);
    arrRes.push(mapped);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

there is some function `fn` passed as argument and array `arr`

`arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));` - means:

1. take **value** from `arr` (index is `i`)
2. execute function `fn`  with **value** as a parameter
3. whatever is result, push it to `arrRes`

example

```js
function arrayCalc (arr, fn) {

    arrRes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        arrRes.push(fn(arr[i])); 

    }
    return arrRes;
};

const someArr = [1,2,3];

function someFunction(number) {
  return number * 10;
}

function someOtherFunction(number) {
  return `${number}_Z`;
}

console.log(arrayCalc(someArr, someFunction)) // [10, 20, 30]
console.log(arrayCalc(someArr, someOtherFunction)) // ['1_Z', '2_Z', '3_Z']
```

Comment: Since you only use the `someFunction` and `someOtherFucntion` once I'd pass them directly to to `arrayCalc` which removes a lot of the noise from the answer imo. `arrayCalc([1,2,3], n => n * 10)`, but in the end that's just personal preference. If OP is not familiar with arrow function the normal function definition might even be better suited.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, agree with arrow functions. updated answer.